# Nexus 5 usb drivers and android device monitor

Tags: android, device-driver

For a while now i'm trying to connect my Nexus 5 to my computer. My smartphone is recognized and the drivers are up to date and correctly installed. But i can't still use file explorer to transfer files.

[image]

And my second big problem is when i use Android Studio. I want use my phone to test my application but it's impossible. Android Device Monitor don't want recognize my phone because the necessary permissions to confirm not appearing on my smartphone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable USB debugging in your phone setting.

In case you don't find it, please go to About phone -> press build number several times, then you will activate the developer module of your nexus.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be cause by insufficient permission of adb. Here is the personal suggestion. Run cmd as administrator and restart the adb daemon to fix the problem.

```
> adb kill-server
> adb start-server
```

Comment: it's not working, my phone don't show me the notification to authentifiate the device